# How do I apply a formula to each value in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I've created a formula that calculates the exponential moving average of data:

```
myEMA <- function(price, n) {
  ema <- c()
  data_start <- which(!is.na(price))[1]
  ema[1:data_start+n-2] <- NA
  ema[data_start+n-1] <- mean(price[data_start:(data_start+n-1)])
  beta <- 2/(n+1)
  for(i in (data_start+n):length(price)) {
    ema[i] <- beta*price[i] +
      (1-beta)*ema[i-1]
  }
  ema <- reclass(ema,price)
  return(ema)
}
```

The data I'm using is:

```
pricesupdated <- data.frame(a = seq(1,100), b = seq(1,200,2), c = c(NA,NA,NA,seq(1,97)))
```

I would like to create a dataframe where I apply the formula to each variable in my above data.frame. My attempt was:

```
frameddata <- data.frame(myEMA(pricesupdated,12))
```

But the error message that I get is:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': undefined columns selected

I'm able to print the answer that I want, but not create a dataframe...

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `myEMA()` is a function, not a formula. Check out `help("function")` and `help("formula")` for details on what the distinction is.

The `myEMA()` function takes a numeric vector as its first argument and returns a numeric vector with the same dimensions as its first argument.

A `data.frame` object is bascially just a list of vectors with a special class attribute. The most common way to repeat a function call across each element in a list is to use one of the `*apply` family of functions. For example, you can use `lapply()`, which will calls myEMA once on each variable in `pricesupdated` and returns a list with one element per function call containing that function call's returned value (a numeric vector). This list can be easily converted back to `data.frame()` since all its elements have the same length:

```
results <- lapply(pricesupdated, myEMA, n = 12)

# look at the structure of the results object
> str(results)
List of 3
$ a: num [1:100] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ b: num [1:100] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ c: num [1:100] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

frameddata <- as.data.frame(results)

# look at the top 15 records in this object

> head(frameddata, 15)
      a   b    c
1     NA  NA   NA
2     NA  NA   NA
3     NA  NA   NA
4     NA  NA   NA
5     NA  NA   NA
6     NA  NA   NA
7     NA  NA   NA
8     NA  NA   NA
9     NA  NA   NA
10    NA  NA   NA
11    NA  NA   NA
12   6.5  12   NA
13   7.5  14   NA
14   8.5  16   NA
15   9.5  18  6.5
```

Comment: Thanks! This works brilliantly. 

I'm intrigued... and this is where I was getting stuck... why is the code:
' results <- lapply(pricesupdated, myEMA, n = 12) '

And not what I originally tried:
' results <- lapply(pricesupdated, myEMA(pricesupdated, 12) '

I.e. why does the specification not occur in the brackets as I had created the function?

Comment: The `FUN` formal argument to an `*apply*` family function expects a `function` object. `myEMA` is a *function*. `myEMA(pricesupdated, 12)` is a *function call* - a request to the interpreter to run a function with arguments. Function calls can't serve as arguments to `FUN` unless they return a `function` object. Also, `pricesupdated` can't be an argument to `price` in myEMA because it's not a vector. `lapply` composes and performs function calls for you with FUN as a template. You get `list(a = myEMA(pricesupdated$a, n = 12), myEMA(b = pricesupdated$b, 12), c = myEMA(pricesupdated$c, 12))`.

Comment: That's an incredibly helpful answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The question is likely a duplicate, ...
but the `apply`-family might help, e.g.

```
sapply(pricesupdated, myEMA, n=12)
```

for reproducibilty, it would be benificial to add `require(pec)`